# Databinding textbox to a structure

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I am using a structure and serializing it to SQL server. I am trying to databind a few masked & normal textboxes to this structure so when I read the data back into my structure it will auto populate my bound textboxes but it doesn't work...I think my binding is maybe incorrect syntax? Can somebody lend a hand? Thank you!

```vb
<Serializable()>
Private Enum PhoneTypes
    <Description("New phoneline")> [NewLine] = 1
    <Description("Existing phoneline")> [ExistingLine] = 2
    <Description("Voicemail only")> [VoicemailOnly] = 3
End Enum

'this is for the phones tab to serialize it and store it in the database 
<Serializable()>
Private Structure Phones
    Public Property PhoneNeeds As PhoneTypes
    Public Property PhoneNumber As String
    Public Property Extension As String
    Public Property Notes As String
End Structure

Private PhoneTab As new Phones

Private Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    InitPhones()
    DoStuff()
End Sub

Private Sub InitPhones()
    txtPhoneNotes.DataBindings.Add("Text", PhoneTab, "Notes")
    txtPhoneNumber.DataBindings.Add("Text", PhoneTab, "PhoneNumber")
    txtExtension.DataBindings.Add("Text", PhoneTab, "Extension")
End Sub

Private Sub DoStuff()
    PhoneTab = mod_Global.Deserialize(Of Phones)(.Item("User_Needed_Phones"))
    MsgBox(PhoneTab.Notes) '<--- this works and I can see the values contained in my structure but does not auto populate the textbox from the binding 
End If
```

Comment: Where are you calling `InitPhones()` ... ? ...

Comment: In my form load event

Comment: If your syntax was incorrect, I would think you would get a compile time error. So I assume you get no errors. You should show what a `PhoneTab` object is. We can see in the code that one is created and you note it has values, however, it is unclear what a `PhoneTab` object is or if it has the properties you show in the binding statements.

Comment: I declared it in my shared code above. It's a structure calles Phones. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I was looking at the definition incorrectly. Well… if you are calling `InitPhones()` AFTER you call the last two line of code you show… then I can not think of why it shouldn’t work. I find the use of the `With` statements odd and unnecessary. Can you show the code that calls `InitPhone` in relation to the last two lines of code? I would think it would be right after the last line and am curious why it isn’t there.

Comment: I cleaned up the code a bit. There are items snipped that are unreleated to this question so I removed them in the with statements...hopefully this makes more sense now.

Comment: Have you tried to call `InitPhones()` AFTER you call `DoStuf()`? In my test this worked. However, you need to keep in mind that if you change the text in the text box, then the underlying data binding data source will get update also. However, this does not work the other way around. In other words, if you change the text in a property in the the data source, then the text box will NOT reflect this change… you will need to clear the binding and reset it.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: Also, in my tests… it appears that the  `Phones` “STRUCTURE” is not getting set when the text box changes. I switched it to a Class and it worked as expected. I previously made that change and did not think to note it. You can change a property in the `TabPhone` code wise, however it does not appear to work when the text box changes unless `Phones` is a Class.

Comment: @JohnG OP Even if the OP use a class, it doesn't work. He have setup databinding to an instance of object which is in variable `x`, later he has assigned a new instance of object to the variable. It doesn't change anything because the Binding object is still pointing to the other value.

Comment: @JohnG But you are right in your finding; databinding to structures is half-way supported; and it makes sense, because the time that you pass your structure to constructor of the Binding class, it copies the values and shows the values in the bound controls. But later, when the control value changes, it pushed the updated to the *COPY* of your structure. And you do not see any update.

Comment: The fix is pretty simple, first load data, then do databinding, but it will be still half-way. You can see the values in your control, but if you modify the values in control, they will not be written back to the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL; DR;** The case is an interesting one however the fix is pretty simple and if you are looking for the fix, jump to end of the post to the **Fix** section.

---

If you are interested to pay more attention to the details, continue reading here. Consider the following facts:

- Databinding to structures is half-way supported. It means, right after the databinding, you can see the property value of the structure in the control property. But later, if you modify control property value, the changes will not be reflected into your structure. Also if you modify the structure property value the changes will not be reflected to the control property.
  That's because when you setup databinding to a structure, the value of your structure will be copied to the Binding class, and later when you update your control or the values of the *COPY* will be updates, or if you assign a new value to property of your original structure, the *COPY* will not see the changes.
  Also even if you use a class, when you modify property values of your object, the changes will be reflected in the control immediately, only if your class implement the INotifyPropertyChanged correctly.
- Even if you use a class, assuming you have an object in a variable `v`, and you setup databinding to that object, later if you assign a new instance to variable `v`, it has nothing to do with the databinding. Variable `v` now is pointing to a new instance of your object and the datavbinding keeps using the previous instance of the object.

I believe reading a bit more about [Value Types and Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
 will help you to get a better understanding of the current situation.

Here is a simplified version of your code:

```
1: dim x = New MyStructure()
2: textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", x , "MyProperty")
3: Dim x =  LoadAnotherMyStructure()
```

In line two, you are setting databinding to an instance of MyStructure; It basically copies the value of `x` into the constructor of `Binding` class and then it doesn't have any idea about what happens for the `x` later; it cannot monitor it.

It's just able to load the value of `MyProperty` of x which you have in line 1 and show it in `textBox1.Text`, but later, if you assign a new Structure to `x` or modify value of `x.MyProperty` then `textBox1.Text` will not be updated.

Also if you change the value of the `textBox1.Text`, the change will not be reflected to the structure.

---

### Fix

The fix is pretty simple here:

```
1: Dim x =  LoadAnotherMyStructure()
2: textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", x , "MyProperty")
```

But keep in mind, it will be still half-way. You can see the values in your control, but if you modify the values in control, they will not be written back to the structure.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I will not deny that initially, I was mistaken in how I thought this worked. After some research and your comments I think I have a little better understanding of how it actually does work. I was unaware that the “Structrue” would not get updated if it was used as a binding data source. I rarely use structures and changed it to a Class early in my tests yet I neglected to note this in my comments. Again, thank you for you useful and helpful comments.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your first comment in the original question. You are correct in that if you… _”have setup databinding to an instance of object which is in variable x, later he has assigned a new instance of object to the variable. It doesn't change anything because the Binding object is still pointing to the other value.”_ … this is true, I did test this and it makes sense. However…

Comment: I do not see where … _”later he has assigned a new instance of object to the variable.”_ … Obviously, if `x` is assigned a “new” `x` object… as you state, that is NOT going to “update” the text boxes that are currently “bound” to object `x` and the code would need to clear and reset the text box bindings.

Comment: However, in the limited posted code, I do not see where the OP is doing this unless I am missing something or just not reading the comment correctly? Lastly, before your comments and my little research and tests… I would have disagreed with that statement. I am now aware of the class needing to correctly implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to have the text box update when the bound data object changes. I loathe posting incorrect info and will be more careful in the future. Again thanks for the useful and needed info 

Comment: @JohnG Thank you for the detailed and valuable feedback. I believe you have got all the points that I mentioned in the comments and in the answer. Just to point out the place that  *… ”later he has assigned a new instance of object to the variable.” ...* : He first declare `Private PhoneTab As new Phones` , then setup databinding to this instance in `InitPhones()`, and later assign a new instance to `PhoneTab` in `DoStuff()`.

Comment: “_He first declare Private PhoneTab As new Phones , then setup databinding to this instance in InitPhones(), and later assign a new instance to PhoneTab in DoStuff()”_ . …. I had switched the `InitPhones` and `DoStuff` order… Blushing … Face Palm… I see it now. Again thanks.

Comment: No problem, my pleasure :)